# How to display parent node attribute value with associated child node attribute values sequentially?

Tags: java, xml

I'm a total newbie to java programming but I'm loving it thus far, however I have run into a brick wall with this one.

- **Objective**

get parent node and display the name
then get specified associated child node and display the name rinse and repeat for each parent node of the same type.

Please see attached sample code for details, I want to get "Page Name" (once) i.e. "Report Page" and then get "query name (once) i.e "Prompt Year", then get all the "data Item Name" i.e. "Year" for the the "query node and then repeat for each additional but different page, query and data item in the list. I hope I have been clear enough, but please let me know if you need further information.

```
 <page name="Report Page">
</query><query name="Prompt Year">
      <source>
        <model/>
      </source>
      <selection>
        <dataItem aggregate="none" name="Year" rollupAggregate="none">
          <expression>'Year In Question'</expression>
        </dataItem>
      </selection>
      <queryHints>
        <useForParameterInfo value="true"/>
        <localCache value="true"/>
      </queryHints>
    </query><query name="Prompt Month">
      <source>
        <model/>
      </source>
      <selection>
        <dataItem aggregate="none" name="Month" rollupAggregate="none">
          <expression>'My Legal Entity'
</expression>
        </dataItem>
        <dataItem name="Reporting Month" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
          <expression>'Month In Question'</expression>
        </dataItem>
        <dataItem name="Month Name" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none">
          <expression>'Month Label'</expression>
        </dataItem>
      </selection>
      <queryHints>
        <useForParameterInfo value="true"/>
        <localCache value="true"/>
      </queryHints>
    </query><query name="Prompt Entity">
            <source>
                <model/>
            </source>
            <selection><dataItem name="Entities" aggregate="none" rollupAggregate="none"><expression>'Legal Entity Abroad'
            </expression></dataItem></selection>
        <queryHints><useForParameterInfo value="true"/><localCache value="true"/></queryHints></query>
        </page>
```